# Select one (this) item from <li> (jQuery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, this

I have a `<ul>` list in my HTML, and inside each `<li>` within that, I have an element with the id `vid`.

With jQuery, I want to make it so that when I click the title of each `<li>`, the `#vid` element in *that* `<li>` (just the one that was clicked) will appear/disappear.

My code to toggle the `#vid` div works, but it affects all of the `#vid` elements, not just one.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">First Title</h3>
      <p class="tags">tags, tags, tags</p>
      <div id="vid">
  Now you see me!
</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">Second Title</h3>
      <p class="tags">etc, etc, etc</p>
      <div id="vid">
  Now you see me!
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var thisli = $('li', this);
  var thisvid = $('#vid', thisli);
  var clicks = 0;

  $('h3', this).click(function() {
    if(clicks % 2 === 0){
      $(thisvid, this).show();
      }else{
      $(thisvid, this).hide();
        }
    ++clicks;
});
  });
```

Comment: IDs must be used once on a page.

Comment: Get rid of the ID attributes as well as the `thisli` and `thisvid` variables. Just assign the click handler to the `h3` elements, and then inside use `$(this).next().next().show()`

Comment: Overall, none of your `$(... , this)` calls make much sense. I think maybe you're throwing the `, this` in there because you saw others do it.

Comment: I used `this` because all the `#vid`s were toggling. I changed it from an id to a class, but come up with the same problem. As for the code you suggested, could you give me an idea of where to put it?

Comment: In place of the `$(thisvid, this).show()` and the `.hide()` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#ID` should be **unique**

so I use `class="vid"` in the code below.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("h3").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".vid").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <h3 class="title">First Title</h3>
    <p class="tags">tags, tags, tags</p>
    <div class="vid">
      Now you see me!
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="title">Second Title</h3>
    <p class="tags">etc, etc, etc</p>
    <div class="vid">
      Now you see me!
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```